# "No such file or directory" when using find with -exec option

Tags: linux

I'm trying to understand how to delete directories using the Linux find command with -exec option, without getting a "No such file or directory" response.
On my Raspberry Pi I go to /home/pi and type:
`mkdir testing`
So now I have created a new directory named /home/pi/testing. Next I try to delete the directory using this command:

```
find /home/pi/testing -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I get the following response:

```
find: '/home/pi/testing': No such file or directory
```

But the /home/pi/testing directory is gone. So the command seemed effective, but why the "No such file or directory" error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find is trying to enter the directory after it has been deleted. If you add the `-depth` option to your command line, `find` will run in depth-first mode in which it will attempt to process the contents of the directory before deleting it:

```
find /home/pi/testing -depth -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

That said, your `find` command line isn't very useful: for this operation, you would generally just run `rm -rf /home/pi/testing`.

Comment: This helped, thanks a lot! Yes, ultimately I want to use the `find` command for more advanced operations than this, but wanted to make the example as simple as possible.